# convert 'std::initializer_list<int>' to 'int'

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Why I can not use variable assigned using "initializer_list" as "normal" variable?

code:

```
void stovr(int a){}
int main() {

   auto v {5}; // v is std::initializer_list<int>
   stovr(v);  // cannot convert 'std::initializer_list<int>' to 'int'

}
```

- Why there is not implicit conversation? (edit: because`v` is list )) )
- Why `v` is `list` and is not `int`?

Comment: As far as I know - this strange behavior was fixed in newer C++ standard versions.

Comment: Implicitly converting something that represents "many things" into a single one of those things doesn't make much sense, and could easily lead to errors in code.

Comment: @Person.Junkie I doubt it. Allowing that conversion wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: `auto x {15}; // list `    *
`int X {15}; // int ` 

I think it's source of errors for newbie.

Comment: The strange behaviour that was fixed in newer C++ standard versions is what `auto` resolves to. `auto v {5};` now makes `v` an `int`.

Comment: @Person.Junkie Yes, but allowing a conversion from `initializer_list<T>` to `T` would be another source of worse errors for "newbie". It would be like curing a headache by chopping one's head off.

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right. this conversion  is bad idea. 
But `auto v{5}` must be `int` ))

Comment: @Person.Junkie Yes, that would be the right fix, and IIRC that is implemented in C++14.

Comment: There was a good talk on CppCon about quirks of type deduction in C++11/C++14/C++17 by Scott Meyers: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU). Same thing in more details in his new [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) (and there was a free sampler with that chapter as well)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::initializer_list<T>` cannot convert to `T` for the same reason that `T[]` cannot convert to `T`, and `vector<T>` cannot convert to `T`: if you merely know that you have a `std::initializer_list<T>`, you don't know how many elements it has.

`std::initializer_list<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };` is perfectly valid. If there were an implicit conversion from `std::initializer_list<int>` to `int`, which of the values would you expect to see?

Comment: Though this begs for the question "actually, _why_ don't you know?". An initializer certainly list knows the number of items and even exposes a `size` member function. So it would be reasonable to expect (and I guess possible?) that it implements an `operator T` which is tagged with an `enable_if_t(size() == 1, value_type)` or something.

Comment: @Damon No, that wouldn't be possible. `size()` is evaluated at run-time. `enable_if_t` requires a condition that can be evaluated at compile-time. It would be possible if the size were part of the type (`std::initializer_list<int, 1>`), but that has more problems than it solves.

Comment: Unfortunately a call to the `size` member function isn't a constant expression. A shame, really.

Comment: Looks like GCC's `initializer_list` is not standard compliant then. I find a `constexpr` constructor taking an iterator and a size, and a `constexpr` member `size` in my 4.9.2 headers. Though seeing how this apparently "works fine" and there is no good reason not to do it from what I can tell, you could argue that it's really the standard that is wrong.

Comment: @Damon Even if the standard did specify that it should be `constexpr`, it wouldn't work for what you want to use it for. It would only be known for concrete `std::initializer_list<T>` instances, so could not be used as a constant expression in instantiation context.

Answer (score 2):

> "A braced initializer has no type! A braced initializer has no type! A
>   braced initializer has no type! No type corresponds to
>   braced initializer"

(C) Scott Meyers.

This is why auto type deduction of brace-initializer with one element fails to follow intuitive rules in C++11 and C++14.

It is considered a defect in standard by many programmers. That is why proposal [N3922: New Rules for auto deduction from braced-init-list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) exists. Notably:

> For direct list-initialization:
>
> - For a braced-init-list with only a single element, auto deduction will deduce from that entry;
> - For a braced-init-list with more than one element, auto deduction will be ill-formed.

Not sure if it is a breaking change and will all C++14 code work after this.

Source: There was a good talk on CppCon about quirks of type deduction in C++11/C++14/C++17 by Scott Meyers: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU), including brace-initializer auto type deduction (starting from 29:00). Same thing in more details in his new [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) (and there was a free sampler with that chapter as well)

Comment: Well clearly it is a breaking change. `auto x { 1, 2 };` was valid before that change, and is made into an error by that change. `auto x { 1 };` was valid before that change, and has a different meaning after that change.

Comment: @hvd Yes. Let's hope standardization committee would find a compromise between code intuitiveness and compatibility with older standards.

Comment: N3922 has been voted into the working paper at the last committee meeting in Urbana.